# Разные favicon для разных сайтов на одной CMS

Tags: php, .htaccess, cms, favicon, яндекс-поиск

Ситуация: одна CMS, на ней 3 сайта. В Яндексе перепутались фавиконки у всех сайтов, точнее у всех 3х стала одна и та же. Изначально фавиконки были разложены так:

- /assets/sitename1/images/
- /assets/sitename2/images/
- /assets/sitename3/images/

Специалист Яндекса утверждает, что для корректного отображения и исключения путаницы с фавиконками нужно, чтобы путь был таким:

- 1site.ru/favicon.png
- 2site.ru/favicon.png
- 3site.ru/favicon.png

Т.к. CMS одна, то и корневая директория одна на всех. Естественно положить в неё 3 разных файла с одним именем не возможно.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить задачу? Может как-то с помощью .htaccess можно?**

Answer (score 0):

лучший друг всех похапешников, .htaccess который на самом деле mod_rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}=site1.ru
RewriteRule ^favicon\.ico$ /assets/sitename1/images/favicon.ico [L]
```

и так три раза

писал от руки, может понадобиться допиливание

Comment: Сразу падает в 500 internal server error

Answer (score 0):

`Естественно положить в неё 3 разных файла с одним именем не возможно.`
очень даже возможно, но довольно таки неразумно

создаёте отдельную директорию для всяких костылей, там создаете примерно такой php
`<? /* это псевдокод если что, без допиливания точно не запустится */ header("Content-Type: image/png"); include $referer. '.ico'; ?>`

называете его "favicon.ico"
после рядом с ним кладёте .htaccess с
`AddType application/x-httpd-php .ico`

лучше выделите отдельную иконку под каждый скин и к каждому домену прибейте отдельный скин.